PROBLEMA CON ECLIPSELINK Y JAXB
problema con eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):

org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: ParallelWebappClassLo usando JAXB


pon la traza completa ya que esta se lee de abajo hacia arriba
